# Проблема с развертыванием Django на Heroku. Не подцепляются static файлы

Tags: python, django, heroku

Знакомлюсь с Django
Размещаю проект на Heroku
Если `DEBUG=TRUE`, то статика доступна, иначе не доступна...
При этом если войти в bash на Heroku, то можно увидеть, что создаётся одна общая папка staticfiles и в неё успешно перемещаются папки со статикой admin и папка со статикой проекта, однако css и логотип не подцепляются...
Не могу понять в чем дело

Файлы прилагаю:

settings.py

```
    """
Django settings for AutoPoster project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
from django.contrib import staticfiles

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ' тут ключ '

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #Мои приложения
    'AutoPosterApp',
    'users',
    #Сторонние приложения
    'bootstrap4',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'AutoPoster.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'AutoPoster.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "AutoPosterApp/static",
]

#параметр, который устанавливает Bootstrap 4 в качестве структуры стилей по умолчанию для django-crispy-forms

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'


#Мои настройки
LOGIN_URL = '/users/login'

#Настройки Django-bootstrap4
BOOTSTRAP4 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}


#Настройки Heroku Применяются если проект развернут и запускается на Heroku
cwd = os.getcwd()
#
if cwd == '/app' or cwd[:4] == '/tmp':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }

    #Поддержка заголовка 'X-Forwarded-Proto' для request.isSecure().
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    #Разрешены все заголовки хостов.
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['tunderposter.herokuapp.com']

    DEBUG = False

    #Конфигурация статических ресурсов
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.urls import re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    re_path(r'', include('AutoPosterApp.urls', namespace='AutoPosterApp')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

base.html

```html
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'AutoPosterApp/css/main.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

данная [инструкция](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python)
отсылает на python библиотеку [heroku-django](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku)

судя по документации там есть подтягивание статик файлов,попробуй посмотреть ее